# Dealing with factors in cox model using coxph

Tags: categorical-data, survival, interpretation, cox-model

I am trying to analysis a dataset with survival data, I am new to cox model and I am not sure how to interpret covariate factors. I have read the survival R package documentation and online examples but I am still very confused.

The covariate I am trying to understand is frailty and contains three levels: frail, pre-frail, non-frail. I am using:

```r
coxph(Surv(time,status)~ frailty, data=data)
# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ frailty, data = data)
# 
#                    coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z     p
# frailtynon-frail -1.749     0.174    0.443 -3.95 8e-05
# frailtypre-frail -0.415     0.661    0.275 -1.51  0.13
# 
# Likelihood ratio test=21  on 2 df, p=2.78e-05
# n= 151, number of events= 70
```

1. It doesn't give me a line for the level frail, is there a way to get it?
2. The exp(coef) and p-value of the level non-frail are low does it means that going from non-frail to any of the two other levels (frail, pre-frail) as a significant decrease on survival.
3. The p-value for the level pre-frail is not significant, if it is computed using frail and non-frail, is there a way to compute it without using non-frail?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/263595/28500) for some hints. The default in `coxph` is to present results for each level of a factor variable with respect to the factor's baseline level. So you never get a value for the baseline level of the factor; for a p-value there has to be something to compare against. This presentation is true in general for regressions in R. Read up on contrasts if you want to evaluate other comparisons of coefficients.

Comment: Thank you @EdM for the explanation and the link to your other answer. So if I understand correctly, my p-value are computed only against frail which is the first level of my factor and concerning interpretation, non-frail as significant effect on mortality and reduce it by 1-0.174=0.826% in relation to frail. Is that right? Concerning contrasts/design matrix in R I have been reading lots of documentation but never encounter a very good one so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Between the question and your comment there are two questions here: the comparisons that go into the displayed *p*-values, and how to interpret the coefficients in Cox regression.

The default in R, at least, is to present all regression results (linear, Cox, generalized linear, etc.) for levels of a categorical variable with respect to its reference level. This can lead to confusion when statistical packages differ in their choices of reference level, as seen in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/263425/28500). You obviously can't get a comparison of the reference level against itself. In general, you will have 1 less coefficient than you have levels of the variable.

In the semi-parametric Cox regression with results presented this way, the reference survival curve is based on reference levels of categorical variables and values of 0 for continuous variables. This reference survival curve is the logical equivalent of the intercept in linear regression. The regression coefficients (shown as `coef` in the output) are calculated for changes in log-hazard around that baseline; the `exp(coef)` for a variable is thus its hazard ratio relative to baseline. So the interpretation of the coefficient for `non-frail` in your comment is not correct; the hazard ratio for non-frail/frail is what is shown for `exp(coef)`, 0.174; the hazard for non-frail is only 17.4% of the hazard for frail.

If you are interested in testing other combinations of predictors you can define different contrasts. It can be a bit tricky to get started with this; you do have to think carefully about what comparisons you wish to make. [This UCLA page](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-test-contrasts-in-r/) provides one introduction, taking advantage of the `glht()` function in the `multcomp` package to minimize the amount of hand coding that might otherwise be involved. Also take a look at [this Cross Validated page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30602/28500). Practice helps. With Cox models, the linear combinations of factor levels for other contrasts and statistical tests will be taken on the coefficients themselves, not on the hazard ratios. In Cox model coefficients add; hazard ratios multiply.

One final warning: there is a technical meaning of "frailty" in survival analysis that might lead to further confusion. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2818/28500) for one introduction to its extended meaning as a within-group correlation of survival rather than simply an individual's health status.